# Are design pattern identification questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes I can see some questions throw some informations such as codes or UML and request for identifying design pattern used.

As examples, now [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909962) question is closed but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032453) remains opened, my question is, is design pattern identifying questions on topic? If so, where is the line that it is on topic?

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think this is quite a duplicate, as OOP pattern identification is much more involved than just "what's the name for this thing?" But that link is definitely relevant, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** Such questions can be on-topic, yes, but they aren't always, and they're not necessarily great fits for SO, as opposed to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

As [explained in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Specific, focused questions about OOP patterns generally fall in the "specific programming problem" and "software algorithm" categories (and possibly the other categories, as well).

The questions you linked to are very different. The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909962/design-patterns-used-in-this-diagram) involves a link to a somewhat vague and incomplete [UML diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)—actually, more like an [entity-relationship model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)—that provides relatively little information. The question itself boils down to "please identify this pattern or group of patterns." But as explained in the comments, there's not really an identifiable pattern, at all. The diagram shows how the data relates, but not how the program works.

The [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032453/what-is-this-design-pattern) question is much better. It provides code for a series of classes as a concrete example of the pattern(s) of interest to OP. It then asks which design pattern the code fits best.

**Disclaimer:** All that said, in my experience, such questions fit better, are received better, and get better answers on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). YMMV.